# Grails getPeristentValue returning null for clearly existing values

Tags: grails

I'm running into a situation where a record is returning null for getPersistentValue(name) even when I can verify that the value was NOT null.

Test:

```
//get it
def team =Team.get(params.id)
if(team){
      log.debug(team.dateCreated);//logs date correctly
      team.properties=params;
      log.debug(team.getPersistentValue('dateCreated');//logs NULL???
}
```

It does not do this for all records. The only obvious difference I can find is the "version" column kept by grails, but manually messing with this didn't alter the behavior. What situations would cause this method to return null when the record exists and the value was set on it?